# Asynchronous JS and LWCs

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

This is just a question to help my understanding of what is going on under the hood.

If I write a simple JS file to fetch data, like below, I can call .then() and provide the name of the function that the microtask queue will run. The parens get added for me and the data argument is injected.  Everything works.

```
function displayMovie(data:object){
        console.log(data)       
    }


 const movie =    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1');
        movie.then(response => response.json())
            .then(displayMovie)
```

But in an LWC I have to specific this.displaymovie(data) or the callback will never run. I assume it never makes it onto the microtask queue at all.

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class Fetch extends LightningElement {



    connectedCallback() {
        this.getMovie();
    }

    getMovie(){
     const movie =    fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/1');
        movie.then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => this.displayMovie(data))
    }

    displayMovie(data){
       console.log(data);
    }
}
```

I was hoping one of the JS pros could help explain what makes the class model different. I am assuming it is not an LWC specific thing.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the arrow function, but you do need `this`:

```
.then(this.displayMovie)
```

This is because in ES6 classes, you must use `this` to access class properties, including functions.

However, it's usually desirable to use the arrow function to make sure that `this` is set to the correct context.

Comment: Got it,  I am not sure why I did not take the arrow function into consideration. And that required adding the arguments vs letting the JS engine inject them.